# Docker container with Elk stack to browse nginx and tomcat log files

Tags: docker, nginx, elastic-stack

I am trying to debug a production failure involving (multiple) nginx and tomcat logs. I have copied the logs to my dev machine. What is the easiest way for me to import these logs into an elastic/ELK stack to sift through quickly? (Currently, I'm making do with less commands across multiple windows)

So far I've found only generic docker containers (like https://elk-docker.readthedocs.io/) that require me to install filebeat and configure it. However, since my data is static, I would prefer a simpler installation.

Answer (score 0):

What I did earlier is create the ELK stack with docker-compose and ingest the data via 'nc' (netcat). An example can be found at: https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk

You might want to adjust the logstash config, so that it reads and parses your data correctly. If the amount of files is not too big, you can nc them one-by-one and otherwise you can write a small script around it, in bash for example, to loop through the files.